# BootStrap Version Compatibily with Angular Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Which BootStrap local CSS version is compatible to use with AngularJS tpls 0.14.3 version?

Answer (score 0):

I am using version 3.3.5 with no issues.  I've been testing with 3.3.6 and have found no problems so far.